# How to count clicks in pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Im making a towers of hanoi game and im trying to make a function which checks if its a first click (to remove a disk) or a second click (to add a disk to a tower) and i have this function.
My problem is that it only registers the first click

```
# Count clicks
def count_clicks(x, y):
    clicks = []
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        for i in range(0, 1):
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            clicks.append([x, y])
            print clicks
```

Comment: in range(A, B), the last value is to, but NOT includling B, so range(0, 1) is every number from 0 to, but not including 1, so just 0 then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I generate the position of a second click in Pygame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243177/how-can-i-generate-the-position-of-a-second-click-in-pygame)

Answer (score 0):

In your code `event` doesn't belong to the count_clicks function and you are initializing clicks every time.

Consider something like this:

```
clicks = []

for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        for i in range(0, 1):
            x, y = event.pos
            clicks.append([x, y])
            print clicks

    if len(clicks) == 2:
        # do something
        clicks = []
```

Also note that the code uses `event.pos` which indicates where the event took place instead of the current mouse location.